# Wordpress Routes for Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, routes

I have a custom plugin which is located like this

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/test.php?id=1&email=test@test.com
```

I want to be able to call it like this

```
http://example.com/test/?id=1&email=test@test.com
```

What is the best way to do this? a htaccess rule would work but I would like to use the custom wordpress rewrite rules as I am using NGINX in some places and Apache in others

Answer (score 0):

You have to use init hook to check for the desired GET parameters and process the request accordingly. [For More Details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)

init is useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.